# Delphi. Show gotten with idHTTP.Get Unicode text in multilanguage Windows

Tags: delphi, http, unicode, delphi-2010, indy10

I need your help. Please help me.

I have Delphi 2010

I try to idHTTP.Get a file with Unicode text (Russian) from site into MemoryStream on English version of Windows 7.

Then I load this MemoryStream with Unicode text into, for example, Memo.

If I set the Russian language as "Language for non-Unicode programs" in Control Panel the text appear properly in Memo. But if I set Enlish - I get wrong characters (*$^#~!@).

How can I load Russian text in Unicode with idHTTP.Get from site and show it properly in any Windows (Chinese, English etc.)???

Thank you for help!!!

Comment: In addition to writing sentences to describe what you've done, please copy and paste your **code**. Also, use the "contact us" link at the bottom of this page to ask an administrator to merge your multiple accounts into one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest updating to a recent Delphi version that is Unicode enabled.

**Update:** It looks like the memorystream actually contains AnsiText in a specific code page instead of real Unicode text. You can declare an appropriate AnsiString variable with that codepage, load the text into that variable and then load the variable into the memo.

It is hard to tell more without seeing the real data.

Comment: @Michael: D2010 does support Unicode so there should be no problems.

Comment: But I have problems, can it be wrong if I did not set character set/code page in idHTTP?

Comment: You do not set a charset when you send a request to the server (unless you are sending text to the server).  The server tells you the charset encoding of the text that it sends to you in a response.  The latest version of Indy 10 decodes the text using that charset, if it is detected.  If the wrong charset is used to decode the text, that can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

TMemo expects Unicode (UTF-16 encoded) text.  If you download the text using the version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that fills a `TStream`, then you are downloading the raw (usually Ansi encoded) text, and then are responsible for manually decoding that to Unicode before then assigning that to the `TMemo`.

Assuming the webserver is specifying a correct charset for the text in the response headers, then use the version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a `String` instead. `TIdHTTP` will detect the charset and decode the raw data into Unicode for you, eg:

```
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('http://addr_here');
```

Answer (score -1):

- Update to D2009 or higher
- Use components that support unicode (I remember [TMS](http://tmssoftware.com/site/) offers some components)
- Set the character set / code page correctly for the language you are using

Comment: I have Delphi 2010. I am using Memory Stream in idHttp, so idHTTP wil not change characters into other code. I did not set character set / code page. I will try it.

Comment: @Michael: because you are downloading into a `TMemoryStream`, you are receiving the raw encoded data.  You are then responsible for decoding the data yourself before you can display it properly.  Better to let Indy do the decoding for you.